# How can I test a micronaut Service with junit5?

Tags: junit, junit5, micronaut

I tried to run the mathService example presented under:

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#junit5

which should explain testing a micronaut service with junit5.

I added

```
testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
testCompile "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5:1.1.3"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.22.0"
testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0"
```

to my dependencies.

I coded MathService, MathServiceImpl in src/main/java
and MathServiceTest in src/test/java

Syntax check while editing works fine, gradlew build blames

```
package org.junit.jupiter.params.provider does not exist
package io.micronaut.test.annotation does not exist
```

what is contrary to editing where the import of these packages works fine.

junit5 Test runs into error message:

```
org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition [io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension]: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigured build or IDE. Please add the 'micronaut-inject-java' annotation processor to your test processor path (for Java this is the testAnnotationProcessor scope, for Kotlin kaptTest and for Groovy testCompile). See the documentation for reference: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluationException(ConditionEvaluator.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:69)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.lambda$evaluate$0(ConditionEvaluator.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:302)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:723)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:476)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:57)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.shouldBeSkipped(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.shouldBeSkipped(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$checkWhetherSkipped$2(NodeTestTask.java:115)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.checkWhetherSkipped(NodeTestTask.java:115)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$DefaultDynamicTestExecutor.execute(NodeTestTask.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$2(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:375)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:430)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1494)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:430)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1494)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:430)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigured build or IDE. Please add the 'micronaut-inject-java' annotation processor to your test processor path (for Java this is the testAnnotationProcessor scope, for Kotlin kaptTest and for Groovy testCompile). See the documentation for reference: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.evaluateExecutionCondition(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:83)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ConditionEvaluator.java:64)
    ... 107 more
```

this error messgae contains the link

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/

which is exactly where I came from.

Can somene give me some more useful information how to test a micronaut service with junit5 ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior.  If you can share a buildable project which demonstrates the issue, it would likely be trivial to identify what is wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/pstrotmann/mathServiceTest

Comment: I submitted a PR to https://github.com/pstrotmann/mathServiceTest/pull/1 which fixes the test and posted a corresponding answer.  The fix didn't work for the OP so I deleted the answer.  It does work for me.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the answer, which I tested with following result: gradlew build is now running fine, ends with a green BUILD SUCCESSFUL. But junit5 still runs into the former posted error message: org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ConditionEvaluationException: Failed to evaluate condition io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension]: @MicronautTest used on test but no bean definition for the test present. This error indicates a misconfigure ...

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/mathServiceTest.git && cd mathServiceTest/math-service && git checkout fix-test && chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew test` does appear to work.  I am guessing you are running the test with an IDE and perhaps that is misconfigured.  I can run the test successfully with Gradle or with IntelliJ.

Comment: I'm running eclipse

Comment: Have you verified that you have annotation processors properly enabled in the IDE in the context where the test is being run?

Comment: In any case, the PR fixes the problems in the code.  Good luck with the IDE!

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same issue. ./gradlew test runs under eclipse anyway: peter@peter-Kubuntu-20-04:~/microApps/math-service$ ./gradlew test
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster) Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s
4 actionable tasks: 4 up-to-date
peter@peter-Kubuntu-20-04:~/microApps/math-service$

Comment: I want to start the test as a junit5 run configuration from the eclipse dropdown menue, the test with the green/red progression bar.

Comment: That works fine if dependencies and annotation processors are configured correctly in the IDE.

Comment: tried intelliJ now (never did before, nice experience) and it works. Think some reading is necessary concerning coworking eclipse and junit5. I'll figure it out and let you know, thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: FYI... We have a few notes about setting up the IDE at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.3.4/guide/index.html#ideSetup.